# Unable to open pdf generated from server because of "Format error:Not a pdf or corrupted"

Tags: c#

Same code working in development environment.But when deployed in test server .pdf document attachment along with the mail not able to open

```
Byte[] arrPageContent = DownloadData(url)
MemoryStream objMemStrm = new MemoryStream();
objMemStrm.Write(arrPageContent, 0, arrPageContent.Length);
return objMemStrm;
```

but when pdf opened in notepad html content displays.any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully answer your question, but maybe the issue is that you are downloading HTML but your intention is to download a PDF? If so, the obvious first thing to check is that, when switching from your dev environment to your test environment, you are downloading from the *exact same* URI.

As an aside, note that there's a `MemoryStream(Byte[])` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) that simplifies your code:

```
Byte[] arrPageContent = DownloadData(url)
return new MemoryStream(arrPageContent);
```

Comment: When code moved to UAT and Live server pdf generated successfully. My thought on this issue may be internal ip's issue